# generate a range of datetime dates

Tags: python, list, datetime

I'm trying to generate a list of start dates which I'll use to scrape google trends. I need the start dates 3 hours apart, and then I'll generate end dates based on the start date in 4 hour increments, so end date overlaps the next start date by 1 hour.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, date
import pandas as pd
import time

start='2018-06-05T01'
end='2020-11-01T23'

start_date = datetime.strptime(start, '%Y-%m-%dT%H')
end_date = datetime.strptime(end, '%Y-%m-%dT%H')

delta = timedelta(hours=3)

while True:
    date_list = []
    date_list.append(start_date + delta)
    if start_date >= end:
        break
```

This does not seem to work, and I'm not sure how to fix it since I'm not sure how to keep looping until the end date is hit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using `pandas` anyway, try with `date_range`:

```
start_date = pd.to_datetime(start, format='%Y-%m-%dT%H')
end_date = pd.to_datetime(end, format='%Y-%m-%dT%H')
date_list = pd.date_range(start_date, end_date, freq="3H")

>>> date_list
DatetimeIndex(['2018-06-05 01:00:00', '2018-06-05 04:00:00',
               '2018-06-05 07:00:00', '2018-06-05 10:00:00',
               '2018-06-05 13:00:00', '2018-06-05 16:00:00',
               '2018-06-05 19:00:00', '2018-06-05 22:00:00',
               '2018-06-06 01:00:00', '2018-06-06 04:00:00',
               ...
               '2020-10-31 19:00:00', '2020-10-31 22:00:00',
               '2020-11-01 01:00:00', '2020-11-01 04:00:00',
               '2020-11-01 07:00:00', '2020-11-01 10:00:00',
               '2020-11-01 13:00:00', '2020-11-01 16:00:00',
               '2020-11-01 19:00:00', '2020-11-01 22:00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', length=7048, freq='3H')
```

If you don't want this to be a DatetimeIndex, you can use:

```
date_list = pd.date_range(start_date, end_date, freq="3H").tolist()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code assigns an empty list to `date_list` and `start_date` is not changed in every iteration. The `end` variable is a string, not a datetime like `end_date`.

Answer (score 0):

As user5401398 pointed out, you should

1. Move the `date_list` outside the loop
2. Update `start_date` in the loop
3. Compare with the `end_date` instead of the `end` variable, which is a string.

A modified version is in the below.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, date

start='2018-06-05T01'
end='2020-11-01T23'

start_date = datetime.strptime(start, '%Y-%m-%dT%H')
end_date = datetime.strptime(end, '%Y-%m-%dT%H')

delta = timedelta(hours=3)

date_list = [start_date]

while True:
    start_date += delta
    date_list.append(start_date)
    if start_date >= end_date:
        break
print(date_list)
```